# SwiftUI Map() view error: Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to build a small Map app where location for user changes all the time. In general I get latitude and longitude updates all the time. And I need to display them and show the change with sliding animation, simular to Apple FindMyFriend, when it slides over map when they are moving in live.

This is my view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@StateObject var request = Calls()

@State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 56.946285, longitude: 24.105078), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))

var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: $request.users){ $user in
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0)) {
            MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: user.latitude, longitude: user.longitude)){
                Circle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And function call in view model, whitch changes user location, the response is just incoming string from API:

```
    func collectUsers(_ response: String){
    if users.count != 0{
        var data = response.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        data.removeLast()
    
        let updates = self.users.map{ user -> User in
            let newData = updateUserLocation(user: user, input: data)
            return User(id: user.id, name: user.name, image: user.image, latitude: Double(newData[1])!, longitude: Double(newData[2])!)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.users = updates
        }
    }else{
        var userData = response.components(separatedBy: ";")
        userData.removeLast()
        
        let users = userData.compactMap { userString -> User? in
            let userProperties = userString.components(separatedBy: ",")
            
            var idPart = userProperties[0].components(separatedBy: " ")
            if idPart.count == 2{
                idPart.removeFirst()
            }
            
            guard userProperties.count == 5 else { return nil }
            guard let id = Int(idPart[0]),
                  let latitude = Double(userProperties[3]),
                  let longitude = Double(userProperties[4]) else { return nil }
            
            return User(id: id, name: userProperties[1], image: userProperties[2], latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.users = users
        }
    }
}
```

And ofcourse my @Published:

```
class Calls: ObservableObject{
@Published var users = [User]()
```

When I use the MapMarker instead of MapAnnotation the error does not appier. I would use marker, but I need each user view in map to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any one stumbles with the same issue. I spent entire day to solve this, but the awnser is that in Xcode 14 it is a bug. After I installer Xcode 13.4.1 error messages disappiered.

Comment: Is it safe to ignore it? Is it safe to release to production? 

Answer (score 0):

I also had one of these warnings appear when I upgraded to Xcode 14, but by clicking on it to show its stack trace, it revealed a case where I was indeed writing to a published var inside a view update, that I was then able to remove.  What does the warning's stack trace show in your case?